# finding difference between 2 dates stored in day,month,dd,yyyy

Tags: c#

I have used DATEDIFF function but since it requires yyyy/mm/dd this code is giving wrong value ,because i have stored date from date time picker in this formate day,month,dd,yyyy

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
DBHandling db = new DBHandling();

db.GetDataset(" select JoiningDate from Emp where name = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", ref ds);
db.GetDataset(" select LeavingDate from AddDate where name = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", ref ds1);

string date1, date2;
date1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
date2 = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
db.GetDataset("select DATEDIFF(day,2008/1/15,2008/1/12) ", ref ds2);
textBox5.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    }
```

so how should i do this so that i will  gate right Difference between 2 dates i.e number of days between 2 dates,thanks in advance

Comment: This is surely no pure C code. My guess is that this is C#, am I right?

Comment: Retagged. We should have tags like "looks-like-c" or "looks-like-java" .)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking up [Timespan](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/458-How-find-difference-between-two-Dates-C-or.aspx).

Get your two dates and then use the timespan to subtract one from the other.  Then the timespan object can tell you how many seconds,days,hours etc... of a difference tehre is.

If the dates are in two separate formats, than convert them to the same format. You can do this in your SQL using CAST or CONVERT or using C#.

Here is a good [link on formatting dates.](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Also, your SQL is wide open to SQL Injection attacks.  You should be using parameterized queries at the least.

Comment: dates are in same formate,and i am using convert like this,bt i am getting error CONVERT(string(24),date1,120); and i dont know how to use it exactly here,i am using 120 ,so that i can use DATEDIFF

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DateDiff** utility of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx).